# Inheritance extends through does not allow to use the parent property

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I am Russian, I write with a translator.
In the class **"Base"** has a private property **"items"**. This array. I am creating a class of **"UserBase"** includes the **"Base"** class (extends). In this class, I need to implement a function that uses the **"items"**. But for some reason it does not work. I'm trying to bring to check the **"items"** through *var_dump()* in the class, and nothing. *NULL*. Help :c

Comment: If you're Russian - then http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ is for you.

Comment: [Property visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make `items` a protected member so the child class can **access** it. Child classes will inherit the private property, but won't be able to access it.

`var_dump` will show all properties of the class, even if they are private, so you should only use that for debugging purposes.